# When I run the command 'ls' in a Linux system, nothing happened

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I was trying to re-implement a simple linux file system. I implemented the function `iterate_dir()`, while I was testing if it could work successfully, I ran the command `ls` and nothing happened, no errors reported either.(I had created some files before running the command).
It will be really helpful if you could help me figure that out. Thanks in advance.

Ubuntu 22.04 & Linux 5.15.0-56-generic x86_64 is used.

code:

```
struct dir_entry {
    char filename[MAXLEN];
    uint8_t idx;
};


struct file_blk {
    uint8_t busy;
    mode_t mode;
    uint8_t idx;

    union {
        uint8_t file_size;
        uint8_t dir_children;
    };
    char data[0];
};


static int evanfs_iterate(struct file *filp, struct dir_context *ctx)
{
    loff_t pos;
    struct file_blk *blk;
    struct dir_entry *entry;
    int i;

    pos = ctx->pos;
    if (pos)
        return 0;

    blk = (struct file_blk *)file_inode(filp)->i_private;

    if (!S_ISDIR(blk->mode)) {
        return -ENOTDIR;
    }

    entry = (struct dir_entry *)&blk->data[0];
    for (i = 0; i < blk->dir_children; i++) {
        dir_emit(ctx, entry[i].filename, MAXLEN, pos, entry[i].idx);
        pos += sizeof(struct dir_entry);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and here are what it looked like when I ran the command:
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

commands in text format:

```
root@evan-virtual-machine:/home/evan/src/evanfs# make
make -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-135-generic/build/ M=home/evan/src/evanfs modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-135-generic'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-135-generic'
root@evan-virtual-machine:/home/evan/src/evanfs# insmod ./evanfs.ko
root@evan-virtual-machine:/home/evan/src/evanfs# insmod mount -t evanfs none /mnt
root@evan-virtual-machine:/home/evan/src/evanfs# cd /mnt/
root@evan-virtual-machine:/mnt# mkdir dir1
root@evan-virtual-machine:/mnt# echo 111 > ./dir1/a
root@evan-virtual-machine:/mnt# cat ./dir1/a
111
root@evan-virtual-machine:/mnt# ls
```

Comment: Use text instead of images.

Comment: You might want to run strace ls to see where it hangs.

Comment: Ok, but I don't think the commands in those images could contribute to solving the problem, because no errors were reported.

Comment: Text is searchable.  insmod, how you mount it, those might be of interest to others.

Comment: OK, I'll modify the post but it may take a while

Comment: Whether function `evanfs_iterate` is ever called during `ls`? Whether it actually performs iterations during that call? You could easily check these facts by adding `printk` into corresponding lines of your code.